# How to write mediapipe face mesh 468 landmarks into FBX file format using Python?

Tags: python, 3d, mediapipe, fbx, face-landmark

I want to write or store mediapipe face landmarks to a FBX file format.

I have tried with multiple way like using fbx, pyfbx and python fbx sdk but not a single library gives me a correct results, I have to use python version 3.7 or above for my further project code.

I am able to create obj file in which I am having 468 3D face landmarks but when I try to write or convert this content of obj to fbx using aspose.3d library it's showing that model is empty.

I think all the libraries which I mentioned above are required to have python lower version that's why the code is not working for conversion into fbx.

Please reply as soon as possible!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The issue looks related to OBJ to FBX Conversion. We also need to check whether FBX format has support for these elements. Can you please create a post in Aspose.3D support forum (https://forum.aspose.com/c/3d) while sharing your sample file and the code snippet with us. We will test the scenario in our environment and address it accordingly. This is Asad Ali and I am Developer Evangelist at Aspose.